# Match string before special char

Tags: java, regex, string, char, match

I'm newbie to java and I'm stuck on a function.

I have a string : `"test lala idea<I want potatoes<"`.

and I want to math the text before the `"<"`.

example :

```
Str[0] = test lala idea
Str[1] = I want potatoes
```

I try to use RegEx but everythig has not worked.
So if anyone has an idea?
Sorry for my english skills.
Thanks.

Comment: Look into the `split()` function in the String class. Google for Javadocs.

Comment: What is the RegEx/code you have used? It might have done a greedy match matching all the text before the second <.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a solution:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    String test = "test lala idea<I want potatoes<";

    String piecesOfTest[] = test.split("<"); 
    // if you need to split by a dot you need to use "\\."

    System.out.println(piecesOfTest[0]); 
    // prints "test lala idea"
    System.out.println(piecesOfTest[1]); 
    // prints "I want potatoes"

    // Here goes a for loop in case you want to 
    // print the array position by position

}
```

In this case split takes "test lala idea" (**which goes from beginnning until the first '<'**) and *saves inside piecesOfTest[0]* (This is just an explanation). Then takes "I want potatoes" (**from first '<' util the second '<'**) and *saves it to piecesOfTest[1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2959259/ambigram-maker)*, so the next position of the array.

In case you want to print this in a loop you could follow the next steps (this loop should be placed only after `.split(regex)` is run:

```
for(int i = 0; i < piecesOfTest.length; i++){

  // 'i' works as an index, so it will be run for i=0, and i=1, due to the condition 
  // (run while) `i < piecesOfTest.length`, in this case piecesOfTest.length will be 2. 
  // but will never be run for i=2, due to (as I said) the condition of run while i < 2

  System.out.println(piecesOfTest[i]);

}
```

Just for the sake of learning, as [ambigram_maker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2959259/ambigram-maker) stated, you can also use a 'for each' structure:

```
for (String element: piecesOfTest)

    // for each loop, each position of the array is stored inside element
    // So in the first loop piecesOfTest[0] will be stored inside element, for the
    // second loop piecesOfTest[1] will be stored inside element, and so on

    System.out.println(element);

}
```

Comment: Thank you :D but have you an idea to make a loop to print in console? @ederollora

Comment: Please, mark my answer as correct so that we can close this question. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should demonstrate the use of `for...each` loop... That's what's everyone's using now!

Comment: While it is true that split uses regex and in regex some characters are special and need to be escaped, `<` is not one of them so `split("<")` is perfectly fine in this case.

Comment: True Pshemo, for example '-', if i'm not wrong can also be used as splitter symbol without the need of \\. But for example the dot'\\.' need to be scaped. I'll modify the code and remove the \\, thanks.